# Интерфейс кастомного View

Tags: android, view

Есть кастомная кнопка, из нее надо в фрагмент передать свои параметры, для этого использую интерфейс:

```
    public interface ColorButtonClickListener{
    public void onClickButton(View view);
}
```

Теперь по клику вызываю этот интерфейс и передаю его методу контекст:

```
ColorButtonClickListener colorButton = (ColorButtonClickListener) getContext();
            colorButton.onClickButton(this);
```

В момент клика возникает исключение:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: ua.com.tarde.finish_paint.MainActivity cannot be cast to ua.com.tarde.finish_paint.Views.ColorButton$ColorButtonClickListener
                  at ua.com.tarde.finish_paint.Views.ColorButton.onTouchEvent(ColorButton.java:106)
```

Ошибку выдает той строке, где я привожу интерфейс. При реализации интерфейса MainActivity ошибки нет. Я понимаю что фрагмент отдельно от activity не живет, и проблема где то в этом. Я просто не понимаю, почему реализацию нажатий нельзя поместить в фрагмент, ведь эти кнопки там и находятся.На этом логика приложения строится.

Comment: Покажите код класса кастомной кнопки и разметку фрагмента. Пока вопрос непонятен.

Comment: Спасибо, ниже мне ответили на вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `getContext()` должен возвращать нечто, наследующее контекст. Fragment не наследует контекст и его метод `getContext()` на самом деле вызывает его метод `getActivity()`. Таким образом у вас и выходит актвити при запросе контекста.

Вам надо так делать:

1. В вашей вьюхе сделать поле для ссылки на интерфейс.
2. Сделать сеттер для него.
3. Во фрагменте реализовать интерфейс
4. После загрузки разметки фрагмента найти вашу вьюху в разметке и присвоить ей ссылку на фрагмент через сеттер из п2
5. В нужный момент вызывать метод интерфейса из вьюхи через переменную вьюхи, коя хранит ссылку на реализацию интерфеса, т.е. через переменную из п1

Answer (score 2):

Не все сразу стало понятно, но в конце концов разобрался. Как выше и советовали:

1. Сделал поле для ссылки на интерфейс и сеттер для него.
2. В коде фрагмента нашел кнопку и реализовал ее интерфейс, через сеттер интерфейса передал this. Я так понял это и есть ссылка на фрагмент. Ну и плюс в реализованном методе интерфейса присвоил нужные мне действия.

Все заработало. Спасибо!